# Auto-enabling a bho in internet-explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, installation, registry, bho, silent-installer

last week I downloaded an extension (i.e) for lyrics, and to my amazement it was automatically enabled without the prompt.
As a programmer i'm interested to know how this is done, I already tried to change some reg keys - but with no success.
the program can be found here ( but beware because i think it's malware) :
bobylyrics.co.
I already wasted days on this, and my OCD doesn't let me stop, so please help 8-)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857563/activate-ie-add-ons-from-an-bho

Comment: I have analyzed your extension, and it definitely looks like unwanted software. It is built using the Crossrider extension framework (which uses several methods to ensure that an extension is installed). The "content script" is located at http://app-static.crossrider.com/plugin/apps/37506/js/1_27_153/ie6/app_code.js ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GpfVqxya) (non-SSL..? Seems to contradict [their FAQ](http://crossrider.com/pages/faq#are_auto_code_updates_safe)). This script in turn inserts another script (http://pastebin.com/FfEfjRk2) which inserts yet another script from a very fishy source.

Comment: PS. If you need Lyrics extension for IE (or any other browser),take a look at [Lyrics Here](https://robwu.nl/lyricshere/) (formerly called YouTube Lyrics). In IE8, this extension is auto-enabled using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/953973). The extension is not auto-enabled in IE9+, because I'd like to offer the user the opportunity to enable the extension themselves, instead of using an unsupported method that might trigger AV.

Comment: Some of the working registry keys are mentioned here: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/793809/ie-11-pre-approve-browser-helper-objects-add-ons