# Disabling IE toolbar menu from js using BHO

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, toolbar, bho, ieaddon

I'm working on IE toolbar add-on and wondering if it's possible to access toolbar object from javascript.

I've BHO object and managed to access it in javascript but could not invoke its method from the js. I'm trying to enable and disable the toolbar menus item from javascript.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "managed to access it in javascript but could not invoke its method from the js"? Beware, question is unclear and may be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate IE Add-Ons from an BHO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857563/activate-ie-add-ons-from-an-bho)